# Why would LDA not perform well on a 2 class classification problem?

Tags: classification, matlab, discriminant-analysis, multi-class

I am performing emotion detection on speech samples. I extract say features (energy, pitch, etc) from the speech files and then try to classify the files by performing LDA and using Matlab's `ClassificationDiscriminant.fit()` function.

I measure accuracy by 10-fold cross validation, and I have 6 emotions samples, each having 60 files (total 360).

Now the problem lies in the difference in accuracy on performing the classification between any 2 emotions, and performing classification on all 6. For multiclass case, I get accuracy of about 70-75%, while for the binary classification case, highest figure reached was 58%.

What could be the explanation behind this behaviour, when the entire process remains same for the 2 cases? Same features, same `lda()` and `fit()` functions.

One explanation that I think can be given is that when I take only 2 emotions, thus # of files becoming 120 (60 x 2), the # of features (170) is becoming greater, and perhaps the LDA model is getting over fitted on the training data. Therefore it is not giving correct labels to the testing data.

In case of taking all emotions, hence 360 files (360 > 170), this is not the case. Hence accuracy is somewhat better.

Am I thinking in the right direction, or is the behaviour just a random occurence? (Although I got the same < 58% accuracies for all the 15 possible pairs from 6 emotions)

Comment: Have you tried visualizing the classes, e.g. running a PCA and plotting to classes? Maybe that helps. It could be that the features for any two given emotions are "too close", i.e. LDA cant seperate them well enough. Also, i think the explanation you gave might be reasonable.